# struct array in a mapping updating

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, mapping, struct

```
mapping(address => trnsctn[])   private  transactionsOfAdress;
    struct trnsctn{
        uint256 when;
        uint256 amount;
    }
    uint256 public ege;
    function deposit() public payable {

        transactionsOfAdress[msg.sender].push( trnsctn(block.timestamp, msg.value));
        ege= transactionsOfAdress[msg.sender].length;

    }
    uint256 public ege2= transactionsOfAdress[msg.sender].length;
```

So I have a mapping which stores the transactions of an account. It should work followingly, when this account deposits money the transaction should be added to its trnsctn[] as the last element. When the account deposits money again, transaction should be added as the last element again but without deleting the first transaction. So 2 transactions means 2 elements and the last transaction is the last element. Since the trnsctn[] is a part of the transactionsOfAdress-mapping(storage variable) it should be dynamically resizable. When I deposit money and call ege it returns 1, which means it successfully updates the last element of transactionsOfAdress[msg.sender]. But when I call ege2 it returns 0. From that I understand that what I do stays only in the function and doesnt change anything after the execution of the deposit-function ends. I have tried a lot to overcome this but I can not. Do you have any advices? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, can you clarify your question?

Comment: I want to push trnsctn-structs to trnsctn[]-array of an account by using the mapping. For example account1 sends 2Ethers on 5.04.2022. I want to do

Comment: is transactionsOfAdress[address(account1)].push(trnsctn( block.timestamp of (5.04.2022), 2Ethers)). When I do this it doesnt work. The changes are done inside the function-deposit, but outside of the function everything is still by default value. To show this I declared two uint variables: ege and ege2. ege shows the length of the trnsctn[] after I push the new transaction which is 1. So I succesfully oush the value, but when the execution of function-deposit ends. I see that it didnt push the transaction. So the changes stay in the function-deposit.

Comment: I hope this makes it clearer. If something is still not understandable please give notice